# Issue with Asp:Image button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple Image Button;

```
<asp:ImageButton Visible="false" ID="downloadImgBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/downloadPdf.jpg" onclick="btnDownload_Click" />
```

But some weird issue is it wont Turn Visible when page loads and it a certail condition is met i have a simple line :

```
downloadImgBtn.Visible=true;
```

I can see it going through the line but the Image Button does not turn visible, however on a `<asp:dropdownList` postback i do some same set of lines and it turns visible with the same line:

`downloadImgBtn.Visible=true`;

OK The issue got a bit weirder on more investigation , so when loads i do not even see the Image button in `HTML Source` and when the dropdown post back the source html has it.

After Page load:

```
<div class="col-lg-2"><img alt="Loading" src="../../images/ajax-loader.gif"
style="display:none" id="Img2"></div>
```

After drop down post back:

```
<div class="col-lg-2"> <input type="image" src="../images/downloadPdf.jpg" 
id="downloadImgBtn" name="downloadImgBtn">  &nbsp;&nbsp; <img alt="Loading" src="../..
/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none" id="Img2"></div>
```

I have now even set `ImageButton` to be `Visible=True`.

Also to make sure of the Div or any parent control is not hidden i put a `Label` before the `ImageButton`:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblText">HELLO I AM HERE...</asp:Label>
```

And it shows perfectly fine on Page load ...

Any suggestion?

Comment: The issue might be CSS related too, but Tim Schmelter suggestion here under seems a good thing to check first...

Comment: Can you post a part of your mark-up?

Comment: @RahulSingh .Actually it is as simple as ... IF (i >0) {downloadImgBtn.Visible=true;}

Answer (score 1):

Often when i've had that issue the reason was that one of the control's parent controls was invisible. The `Visible` property is inherited. So maybe it's in a `Panel` which is still `Visible=false`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions it als in the documentation:

> If a container control is not rendered, any controls that it contains
>   will not be rendered even if you set the Visible property of an
>   individual control to true. In that case, the individual control
>   returns false for the Visible property even if you have explicitly set
>   it to true. (That is, if the Visible property of the parent control is
>   set to false, the child control inherits that setting and the setting
>   takes precedence over any local setting.)

---

According to your edited question that the HTML doesn't even contain the control. `Visible` is a server-side property. If you set a control's `Visible`-property to `false` the HTML won't be rendered at all. So you cannot even access it on client-side, only on server-side. After you've made it visible it will be rendered which you can see in the HTML here:

```
<div class="col-lg-2"> <input type="image" src="../images/downloadPdf.jpg" 
id="downloadImgBtn" name="downloadImgBtn">  &nbsp;&nbsp; <img alt="Loading" src="../..
/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none" id="Img2"></div>
```

But you have set it's `display` to `none` which still hides it. Remove that and you're finished.

Comment: I am a bit confused now can you please check updated question.

Comment: @confusedMind: i have edited it. `style="display:none"` makes it invisible on client side.

Comment: That is a differnet Html Image which has 'style="display:none"'.

Comment: @confusedMind: you're right, i have overlooked that. But i don't understand if it's working now since you've mentioned and shown that the image is visible in the HTML. Is it still invisible? Is a `div` or other container control invisible? Show the css `class="col-lg-2`.

Comment: The Image in not Visible in HTML on Page load , but than it is Visible on dropdown post back as on the Html Source in the question above. The class Name remains the same that is never change before or after post back so i dont think that will make a difference here ?

Comment: Also the drop down is right before this Image so this means the Div is visible and no issue , i will now put a button or label in same place as ImageButton and see if some Issue with classes etc or hidden Div it should not show aswell on page load .

Comment: Ok , just put a label "<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblText">HELLO I AM HERE...</asp:Label> " before the Image button it shows fine on page load the image button however still wont.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the image button on the load because of Visible="false"..... This means that the button it is not rendered on the page.

It appers on the postback because you set Visible=true

It you set Visible=true and you don't see it, than check your code. Some lines below Visible=true you have a Visible=false, OR and i suspect this... you have a redirect to the same page.

Comment: I tested it Visible = True now same thing.

Comment: I think it's best if you give us all the page code.

Comment: i think that is too much to copy paste :)